# How to extract number and characters from a tuple in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple list or dictionary as below. Now I want to extract the number and characters (email) separately.

```
('a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk 14', 'aaronz@vt.edu 110', 'ajpoland@iupui.edu 48', 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk 18', 'arwhyte@umich.edu 27', 'bahollad@indiana.edu 4', 'bkirschn@umich.edu 27', 'chmaurer@iupui.edu 111',)


{'a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk': 14, 'aaronz@vt.edu': 110, 'ajpoland@iupui.edu':48, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 18, 'arwhyte@umich.edu': 27, 'bahollad@indiana.edu': 4, 'bkirschn@umich.edu‘: 27, 'chmaurer@iupui.edu’: 111)
```

Then I want to add the max # and email having the max # to a string.

Comment: You question is not clear. Please give the dict in proper format, add your code that you've tried, tell us where you are facing problem and elaborate in details. This is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```
d=('a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk 14', 'aaronz@vt.edu 110', 'ajpoland@iupui.edu 48', 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk 18', 'arwhyte@umich.edu 27', 'bahollad@indiana.edu 4', 'bkirschn@umich.edu 27', 'chmaurer@iupui.edu 111',)

dict1={i.split()[0]:int(i.split()[1]) for i in d}

print(max(dict1),dict1[max(dict1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `max()` like below.

```
d ={'a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk': 14, 'aaronz@vt.edu': 110, 'ajpoland@iupui.edu':48, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 18, 'arwhyte@umich.edu': 27, 'bahollad@indiana.edu': 4, 'bkirschn@umich.edu': 27, 'chmaurer@iupui.edu': 111}

x = max(d.items(), key= lambda y: y[1])
print(x)
```

This gives the maximum number and the associated email.

```
('chmaurer@iupui.edu', 111)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_tuple = ('a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk 14', 'aaronz@vt.edu 110', 'ajpoland@iupui.edu 48', 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk 18', 'arwhyte@umich.edu 27', 'bahollad@indiana.edu 4', 'bkirschn@umich.edu 27', 'chmaurer@iupui.edu 111',)
dict = {}
for val in input_tuple:
    temp_val = val.split(' ')
    dict[temp_val[0]]=int(temp_val[1])
print (dict)
```

Output :
{'aaronz@vt.edu': 110, 'ajpoland@iupui.edu': 48, 'bahollad@indiana.edu': 4, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 18, 'chmaurer@iupui.edu': 111, 'arwhyte@umich.edu': 27, 'bkirschn@umich.edu': 27, 'a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk': 14}

Above will help in extracting number and character from a tuple in python.

Can you clarify on "Then I want to add the max # and email having the max # to a string."

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one solution for you**

```
a_tuple = ('a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk 14', 'aaronz@vt.edu 110', 'ajpoland@iupui.edu 48', 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk 18', 'arwhyte@umich.edu 27', 'bahollad@indiana.edu 4', 'bkirschn@umich.edu 27', 'chmaurer@iupui.edu 111',)
a_dict = {'a.fish@lancaster.ac.uk': 14, 'aaronz@vt.edu': 110, 'ajpoland@iupui.edu':48, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 18, 'arwhyte@umich.edu': 27, 'bahollad@indiana.edu': 4, 'bkirschn@umich.edu': 27, 'chmaurer@iupui.edu': 111}


print("***Tuple***\n")
for each in a_tuple:
    new = each.split(' ')

    for n in new:
        if n.isdigit():
            continue
        print(n)

print("\n***Dictionary***")

for keys in a_dict.keys():
    print(keys)
```